# Google Custom Search Wordpress Sidebar CSS styles squashed

Tags: css, sidebar, google-custom-search

Hi Clever CSS Gurus etc

I've just added Google custom search widget to my wordpress site
I have a problem with the styling though?

Its supposed to appear like this sidebar one - http://googlecustomsearch.blogspot.co.uk/
but on my site it appears like this - http://brightmist.co.uk/blog/

Any ideas on how to fix it?
Thanks for all your help

Judith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you have access to your CSS stylesheet('/wp-content/themes/modernize/style.css'), go to line 40 where it has...

```
tr th, tr td{padding: 9px 20px;}
```

I think the 20px padding is what is squashing it up like that. Thats to generic a style to use really, that will effect every HTML table on your website. If you want certain tables on your website to have that padding, give them a class and apply that padding only to tables with that class. Or try adding...

```
#cse-search-form74 table td{padding: 0; border: none;}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that started me off. I've written a blog post - http://brightmist.co.uk/blog/2013/03/11/how-to-fix-google-custom-search-in-wordpress/